# Параллельные запросы в postgesql

Tags: postgresql, spring, hibernate

Всем привет.

Работаю в связке Java Spring - Hibernate - PostgreSQL. К БД я отсылаю асинхронные запросы в нескольких потоках. По своим задачам и реализации они абсолютно идентичны. Спустя три часа параллельной работы только в одном из потоков возникает ошибка:

"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ОШИБКА: не удалось инициализировать параллельный исполнитель"

В дальнейшее время работы такой ошибки не происходило. Я предположил, что это может быть связано с параметрами max_worker_processes и max_parallel_workers_per_gather в файле postgresql.conf. Изначально они были равны 8. Увеличил число до 20. Теперь подобной ошибки не возникает.

В связи с этим возник вопрос: эта ошибка была какой-то случайностью или действительно необходимо было увеличить число воркеров? Уже можно спокойно продолжать работу и не ожидать подвоха с этой стороны?

Comment: Могу сказать лишь, что `max_worker_processes` > `кол-во ядер` имеет мало смысла. `max_parallel_workers_per_gather` как правило делают `max_worker_processes / 2`. Т.е. если у Вас 4 ядра в машине, ставить `max_worker_processes > 4` почти не имеет смысла.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать! С тех пор подобной ошибки не возникало. Правда, если max_worker_processes работают именно так, как Вы описали, то, что до, что после изменения значений, никакой разницы быть не должно, т.к. значения уже были выше количества ядер. Видимо, работа с БД через многопоточность является не стабильной.